# Sodor Processor Collection. Eclipse Setup

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, riscv, chisel

I'm trying to setup the [Sodor Processor Collection](https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-sodor) (RISC-V) from Github.
My main goal is to setup the 1-Stage Processor in my own chisel project in order to modify it and possibly write a scala testbench.

**Currently i'm doing the following:**

1. Cloning the [chisel template project](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-template) to my local machine
2. Executing "sbt eclipse" in the root folder (with [this tool](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse)). In order to be able to import it in Eclipse
3. Importing the project-template in Eclipse Luna
4. Copying the **common/** and **rv32_1stage/** folders from the Sodor Projects [src/ folder](https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-sodor/tree/master/src) in my project-templates src/ folder.

It then looks like this:

[image]

However, Eclipse shows 72 errors:

```
    not found: object Node  configurations.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 4  Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  consts.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 13 Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  core.scala  /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 21 Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 11 Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  csr.scala   /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 13 Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  decode.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 4  Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 12 Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  htif.scala  /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 4  Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  instructions.scala  /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 6  Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 21 Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  tile.scala  /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 10 Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  top.scala   /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 4  Scala Problem
    not found: object Node  util.scala  /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 9  Scala Problem
    not found: value Lit    decode.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 20 Scala Problem
    not found: value Lit    decode.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 20 Scala Problem
    not found: value Lit    util.scala  /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 131    Scala Problem
    not found: value Literal    decode.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 11 Scala Problem
    overloaded method value apply with alternatives:   (x: String,radix: Int)scala.math.BigInt <and>   (numbits: Int,rnd: scala.util.Random)scala.math.BigInt <and>   (signum: Int,magnitude: Array[Byte])scala.math.BigInt  cannot be applied to (Any, Int)    decode.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 12 Scala Problem
    overloaded method value apply with alternatives:   (x: String,radix: Int)scala.math.BigInt <and>   (numbits: Int,rnd: scala.util.Random)scala.math.BigInt <and>   (signum: Int,magnitude: Array[Byte])scala.math.BigInt  cannot be applied to (Any, Int)    decode.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 12 Scala Problem
    overloaded method value apply with alternatives:   [T <: chisel3.core.Data](size: Int, t: T)chisel3.core.Mem[T] <and>   [T <: chisel3.core.Data](t: T, size: Int)chisel3.core.Mem[T]  cannot be applied to (chisel3.core.UInt, Int, seqRead: Boolean)   memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 86 Scala Problem
    overloaded method value apply with alternatives:   [T <: chisel3.core.Data](size: Int, t: T)chisel3.core.Mem[T] <and>   [T <: chisel3.core.Data](t: T, size: Int)chisel3.core.Mem[T]  cannot be applied to (chisel3.core.UInt, Int, seqRead: Boolean)   memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 87 Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Any  required: chisel3.core.Data  cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 139    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Any  required: chisel3.core.Data  cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 140    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Any  required: chisel3.core.Data  cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 141    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Any  required: chisel3.core.Data  cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 142    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Any  required: chisel3.core.Data  cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 158    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Any  required: chisel3.core.Data  cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 159    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Any  required: chisel3.core.Data  cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 181    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Array[(chisel3.core.UInt, List[chisel3.core.UInt])]  required: Array[(chisel3.util.BitPat, List[?])]  cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 52 Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : chisel3.core.Bool  required: Int  dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 104    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : chisel3.core.Bool  required: Int  dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 105    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : chisel3.core.Bool  required: Int  dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 106    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : chisel3.core.Bool  required: Int  dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 108    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : chisel3.core.Bool  required: Int  dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 227    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : chisel3.core.SInt  required: chisel3.core.UInt    csr.scala   /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 240    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : chisel3.core.UInt  required: Int  dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 101    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : chisel3.core.UInt  required: Int  dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 107    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Int(11)  required: chisel3.UInt     (which expands to)  chisel3.core.UInt dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 108    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Int(12)  required: chisel3.UInt     (which expands to)  chisel3.core.UInt dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 107    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Int(19)  required: chisel3.UInt     (which expands to)  chisel3.core.UInt dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 106    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Int(20)  required: chisel3.UInt     (which expands to)  chisel3.core.UInt dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 104    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Int(20)  required: chisel3.UInt     (which expands to)  chisel3.core.UInt dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 105    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Int(27)  required: chisel3.UInt     (which expands to)  chisel3.core.UInt dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 101    Scala Problem
    type mismatch;  found   : Int(32)  required: chisel3.UInt     (which expands to)  chisel3.core.UInt dpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 227    Scala Problem
    value & is not a member of Chisel.Bits  decode.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 20 Scala Problem
    value & is not a member of Chisel.Bits  util.scala  /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 31 Scala Problem
    value & is not a member of Chisel.Bits  util.scala  /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 41 Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Any    cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 123    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Any    cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 124    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Any    cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 125    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Any    cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 126    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Any    cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 127    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Any    cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 128    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Any    cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 129    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Any    cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 130    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Any    cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 131    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Any    cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 147    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Any    cpath.scala /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/rv32_1stage line 147    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Chisel.Bits    decode.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 20 Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Chisel.Bits    memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 182    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Chisel.Bits    memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 182    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Chisel.Bits    memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 183    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Chisel.Bits    memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 183    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Chisel.Bits    memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 184    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Chisel.Bits    memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 184    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Chisel.Bits    memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 211    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Chisel.Bits    memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 212    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Chisel.Bits    memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 213    Scala Problem
    value === is not a member of Chisel.Bits    memory.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 214    Scala Problem
    value litOf is not a member of Chisel.Bits  decode.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 9  Scala Problem
    value litOf is not a member of Chisel.Bits  decode.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 38 Scala Problem
    value litOf is not a member of Chisel.Bits  decode.scala    /riscv-sodor-own/src/main/scala/common  line 38 Scala Problem
```

If i **directly import** the cloned Sodor Processor Collection project from github into eclipse, it shows **no errors**. But as far as i understood, i can't write a scala testbench there.

I'd very much like to know **if it's even possible** to create a src/main/scala/test/ folder and write a **scala testbench** for the Sodor Processor Collection, like it's always done in the chisel tutorials (e.g. [here](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-tutorial/blob/release/src/test/scala/solutions/Accumulator.scala))

My best guess is, that i have to configure the build.sbt file correctly, but i don't know how. (Please tell me if i'm completely wrong with this setup or missed out on something.)

**In short**

*- Sodor Processor Collection in Eclipse?*

*- Scala testbenches for Sodor Processor Collection?*

*- If yes to the above, how to resolve the errors?*

**EDIT**

After some research i think the main problem lies within the **chisel version compatibility**.
I found [Chisel3 vs. Chisel 2](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/wiki/Chisel3-vs-Chisel2) and saw this:

```
the Node class and object no longer exist (the class should have been private in Chisel2)
```

By **removing** all the unnecessary **import Node._** lines, i eliminated 13 of the errors. But 59 remain..

Comment: Sodor has not been updated to Chisel3. It would be quite a lot of work to do so, including changing out the C++ emulator to use Verilator instead.

Comment: Yes, i ran in some version problems indeed. See your point. Gonna try working with the Rocket Chip Generator as a next step.